Is there a method for creating Hyperlink without setting the hyperlink style
I am looking for a way to set an hyperlink a cell, but without setting the hyperlink style. so basically keep the existing cell formatting.
I know you can set another style, but the original formatting is then gone.
I know you can save the original formatting in a structure or so and reset it afterwards but since there are really a lot of formatting possibilities it's not a nice solution, especially when I need to handle a lot of cells.
I don't want to change the content of the cell (eg the hyperlink function).
I am curious of there are any options for this:).

There's no built-in way to do what you want.

I was afraid of this, but just thought of an idea. what if i change the style of the hyperlink to basically 'nothing', then place the hyperlinks, Remove the style from the cells (replace it with empty style). Then reset the hyperlink style. I am going to test this now

It works. Since there are only a few settings in the hyperlink style, you can copy them easily and set them back when finished. Since I needed to place a lot of hyperlinks on a worksheet it worked ok. The only thing to remember is that all sheets where the hyperlink style is used should be unprotected.

Could you share what you discovered by improving your question and adding the initial code and by adding an answer describing how you solved the issue with the new code so this thread would become useful for others.

I know, but still working on a final solution, the main headage is know the unprotection part, because there might be pw protected sheets.

Don't afraid. Just select a dedicated cell to keep formatting temporary. F4 is the target cell, E6 is the temporary formatting storage.
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    [F4].Copy [E6]
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add [F4], "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
    [E6].Copy
    [F4].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    [E6].Clear
End Sub

If you like to keep characters formatting, refer to another my solution.

Tnx this is also an option. Since I need to perform the action on multiple cells I am going to check both options tnx.

Going through all options, since the hyperlink style basically only changes 3 formats I decided to go for:
 With xlCellFont
    .Name = xlRange.Font.Name
    .Size = xlRange.Font.Size
    .Underline = xlRange.Font.Underline
End With

xlActivesheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=xlActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sheetName & "'!" & goalCell)

xlRange.Font.Underline = xlCellFont.Underline
xlRange.Font.Name = xlCellFont.Name
xlRange.Font.Size = xlCellFont.Size
xlRange.Font.Bold = True
xlRange.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(45, 45, 255))


If you place a hyperlink inside an IF statement or a CHOOSE statement, the original formatting of the cell is not changed. When copying, paste the formula.
=IF(TRUE, HYPERLINK("https://www.stackoverflow.com"))


kept it short & simple +:)
